# EditText value is underlined when set to a TextView - android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a FAB button in my app's MainActivity. An AlertDialog shows up when it gets pressed with an EditText. I'm taking the editText's value and setting it to a text view. but the problem is if I type something for example 'html' (no space after 'l' ) then the word 'html' is underlined, if I type it with a space after 'l' or any word with a space after its last alphabet, the value isn't underlined. Why is that?

Here's the edit text:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/project_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
```

Setting the value to the text view:

```
EditText projectName = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
textView.setText(projectName.getText());
```

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Since that text view isn't even in the layout (you didn't add it to any parent), Its not going to display at all

Comment: This may be due to spell check enabled. To disable it add this to your edittext `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: I've added it to the parent. just didn't show here. Because there's lot of codes. I created a relative layout and set its layout params and stuff like that. So for the simplicity.

Comment: I also added `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try above,

```
EditText projectName = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
String strEditText = projectName.getText().toString();
TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
textView.setText(strEditText);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You find Your EditText Id  and TextView  but the mistake is that you did not get the text of your "EditText"  i.e. take editable text of "EditText" is a "String Variable"
**look at below code.**...

```
EditText your_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Your_EditText_From_XML);
String editTextString = your_editText.getText().toString();
```

And Then Set this String variable to your TextView

```
TextView YourTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
YourTextView.setText(editTextString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason which causes you to get the underline is that **EditText's gettext()** method returns an **Editable** which is somewhat different from **String/CharSequence** datatype which is what your **TextView's settext()** method expects. So all you need to do is to convert that editable text to a string and you'll be done with the work.

Here's a short and sweet answer-

```
tvYourTextView.setText(etYourEditText.getText().toString());
```